# how to remove images during the setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, settimeout

```
        case FOCUS_AA:
        if(keyCode == KEY_RIGHT){
            focus = FOCUS_AB;

            clearTimeout(a);

            document.getElementById("background").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("backLight").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("treeBoard").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("a0").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('banana').play();
            banana1();


            function banana1(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b0").style.display = "block";
                /*var a = setTimeout(apple2, 1000);*/
                b = setTimeout(banana2, 1000);
            }
            function banana2(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b0").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("b1").style.display = "block";
                b = setTimeout(banana3, 1000);
            }
            function banana3(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("b2").style.display = "block";
                b = setTimeout(banana4, 1000);
            }
            function banana4(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("b3").style.display = "block";
                b = setTimeout(banana5, 1000);
            }
            function banana5(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b3").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("b4").style.display = "block";
                b = setTimeout(banana6, 1000);
            }
            function banana6(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b4").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("b5").style.display = "block";
                b = setTimeout(banana7, 1000);
            }
            function banana7(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b5").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("b6").style.display = "block";
                b = setTimeout(banana8, 1000);
            }function banana8(){
                document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("b6").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("b0").style.display = "block";
                b = setTimeout(banana8, 1000);
            }
        }else if(keyCode == KEY_BACK){
            focus == FOCUS_A
            window.location.href = 'Shop.html';
        }
    break;
case FOCUS_AB:
        if(keyCode == KEY_LEFT){
            focus = FOCUS_AA;

            clearTimeout(b);

            document.getElementById("background").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("backLight").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("treeBoard").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("a0").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("b0").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('apple').play();


            apple0();

            function apple0(){
                document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("a0").style.display = "block";
                a = setTimeout(apple1, 1000);
            }
            function apple1(){
                document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("a0").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("a1").style.display = "block";  
                a = setTimeout(apple2, 1000);
            }
            function apple2(){
                document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("a1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "block";  
                a = setTimeout(apple3, 1000);
            }
            function apple3(){
                document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("a2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("a3").style.display = "block";
                a = setTimeout(apple4, 1000);
            }
            function apple4(){
                document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("a3").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("a4").style.display = "block";
                a = setTimeout(apple5, 1000);
            }
            function apple5(){
                document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("a4").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("a5").style.display = "block";
                a = setTimeout(apple6, 1000);
            }
            function apple6(){
                document.getElementById("aImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("a5").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("a0").style.display = "block";
                a = setTimeout(apple6, 1000);
            }
        }else if(keyCode == KEY_RIGHT){
            focus = FOCUS_AC;
            clearTimeout(b);
            document.getElementById('b_').style.display ='none';
            document.getElementById("background").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("backLight").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("treeBoard").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("c0").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("cImg").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("bImg").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("b0").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('cake').play();
            cake1();
            function cake1(){
                document.getElementById("cImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("c0").style.display = "block";
                c = setTimeout(cake2, 1000);
            }
            function cake2(){
                document.getElementById("cImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("c0").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("c1").style.display = "block";
                c = setTimeout(cake3, 1000);
            }
            function cake3(){
                document.getElementById("cImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("c1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("c2").style.display = "block";
                c = setTimeout(cake4, 1000);
            }
            function cake4(){
                document.getElementById("cImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("c2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("c3").style.display = "block";
                c = setTimeout(cake5, 1000);
            }
            function cake5(){
                document.getElementById("cImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("c3").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("c4").style.display = "block";
                c = setTimeout(cake6, 1000);
            }
            function cake6(){
                document.getElementById("cImg").style.display = "block";    
                document.getElementById("c4").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("c0").style.display = "block";
                c = setTimeout(cake6, 1000);
            }
        } else if(keyCode == KEY_BACK){
            focus == FOCUS_B
            window.location.href = 'Shop.html';
        }
    break;
```

this shows using setTimeout to animate the images.
when i press "KEY_RIGHT" : the images stopped and shows next animated image.
but problem is images overlaps with stopped images and the next images.
how do i remove all the stopped or previous images(FOCUS_AA) when key pressed next step(FOCUS_AB)?

Comment: This is extremely confusing to read, I read it five times and still don't know what you are asking. Please provide a jsfiddle or at least all of your code.

Comment: hi im new to javascript so don't have great skills to explain. sorry. but i edited more of my source. hope u understand.thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to animate via jQuery, you could call .stop() on all animations and have the always action on animations would be to hide the photos. That way, even if you were in the middle of an animation, the animation would stop, go immediately to the end and the next animation would go.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Fixed it. Hope this is clearer and completely answers the question.